# How can I make a function to remove double letters in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a function that removes double letters from a string. The function is only supposed to remove double letters next to each other, not in the whole string. e.g 'aabbaa' would become 'aba' (not 'ab'). Im a fairly new to c programming and dont fully understand pointers etc. and need some help. Below is what I have so far. It does not work at all, and I have no idea what to return since when I try and return string[] it has an error:

```
char doubleletter( char *string[] ) {
char surname[25];
int i;
for((i = 1) ; string[i] != '\0' ; i++) {

    if (string[i] == string[(i-1)]) {   //Supposed to compare the ith letter in array with one before
        string[i] = '\0' ;              //Supposed to swap duplicate chars with null
    }


}
surname[25] = string;

return surname ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. It is a clear simple and professionally-looked code.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * unique( char *s ) 
{
    for ( char *p = s, *q = s; *q++; )
    {
        if ( *p != *q ) *++p = *q;
    }

    return s;
}


int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "aabbaa";

    puts( unique( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
aba
```

Also the function can be rewritten the following way that to escape unnecassary copying.

```
char * unique( char *s ) 
{
    for ( char *p = s, *q = s; *q++; )
    {
        if ( *p != *q )
        {
            ( void )( ( ++p != q ) && ( *p = *q ) );
        }
    }

    return s;
}
```

Or

```
char * unique( char *s ) 
{
    for ( char *p = s, *q = s; *q++; )
    {
        if ( *p != *q && ++p != q ) *p = *q;
    }

    return s;
}
```

It seems that the last realization is the best.:)

Comment: Really nice :-) Seems like our logic is same, though I am still trying to grasp, how on this good earth, you managed to put the `NULL` character in the right place :-)

Comment: @nIcE cOw It is indeed the best code among presented here in answers. :)

Comment: @nIcE cOw: The '\0' character is not treated in any special way, so beeing an unique character as well "aabbaa\0" is translated into "aba\0" ;)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: I agree that it is indeed by far, the most professional, but certainly not the most comprehensible for a C newbie :P

Comment: @oo_miguel What about my last realization of the function?

Comment: Ahha nice thought. I am just new to C, so just trying to get a feel of this language. As I share my thoughts with people like yourself(both of you(oo_miguel and Vlad from Moscow)), having some wonderful knowledge of the language, it seems like will help me loads too :-)

Comment: Just a note to people: Code looking professional isn't necessarily professional. What actually makes code professional is factors like readability, portability, error handling and correctness, Not things like: it looks cool because it uses 1 char variable names, lacks parenthesis, curly braces and newlines.

Comment: @Jite It seems that you contradict yourself. How can a program  look professionally if it lacks professional looking as you think?:)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but can you explains somethings for me, like whats the difference between a ++ before and after a variable. And also how the function works at each step?. I thought for a  function you need {intializer ; test expression ; incrementer } but yours appears to have only a intializer and test expression, which is q++ !? Please explain how this works

Comment: @Arthur To understand the difference between *q++ and *++q try the following char *q = "AB"; char *p = q; printf( "%c\n", *p++ ); p = q; printf( "%c\n", *++p );

Comment: @Arthur: `*p++` means, increment p, to point to the next location, but look inside the previous location held by p(or look inside present location and then make p point to next location). Try to read this from `right to left`. Now `*++p` means, (again if you read from right to left) increment the current location of p, and then look inside that location.

Comment: @Arthur As for the condition then the value of expression *q++ is the character *q. If this character is not equal to '\0' then the condition is true.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Assuming random strings of considerable length as input, the second comparison (++p != q) would cost more than gain (concerning speed).  Only in relatively few cases p will equal q. Concerning the size, also your first solution is better. However for short strings, the last realization might be faster.

Comment: @oo_miguel You are wrong. For example a string can have no duplicated characters independing on its size. So to speak about whether p will be equal to q or not is incorrect. It is general purpose function.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Most random strings of considerable size will have duplicates. If you assume strings without duplicates as input, you will not need your function at all ;)

Comment: @oo_miguel Strings can be of any sizes.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Let's take the string: "aabababababababa" as an example? Which of your solutions would be faster in this case?

Comment: @oo_miguel The last solution will be the best. Your approach is in essence wrong.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: As far as I understand your solution, you will have an additional comparison (++p != q) for every character, but the first  in case of the string: "aabababababababa". Please clarify if I'm wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63668/discussion-between-oo-miguel-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @oo_miguel Otherwise you have to do assignments instead of comparisons where they are not needed.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: But in your last solution, you have an assignment AND a comparison, for most characters on most inputs. (Please continue in chat)

Comment: @oo_miguel I have understood your idea. I do not take part in chat.

Comment: @oo_miguel  The function can ve rewritten such a way that at first it searches the first duplicated character without assighmnets and then it will use asiignments.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: I agree! That would possibly be the ultimate solution :)

Comment: @oo_miguel  I have written such a function but comparing it with the original function I do not like that there are now two loops instead of one loop.:)

Answer (score 2):

**First** of all delete those parenthenses aroung `i = 1` in for loop (why you put them there in the first place ?
**Secondly** if you put `\0` in the middle of the string, the string will just get shorter.
`\0` terminates array (string) in C so if you have:
`ababaabababa`
and you replace second 'a' in pair with `\0`:
`ababa\0baba`
effectively for compiler it will be like you just cut this string to:
`ababa`

**Third** error here is probably that you are passing two-dimensional array to function here:
`char *string[]`
This is equivalent to passing `char **string` and essentialy you are passing array of strings while you wanna only to pass a string (which means a pointer, which means an array: `char *string` or ofc `char string[]`)

Next thing: you are making internal assumption that passed string will have less than 24 chars (+ `\0`) but you don't check it anywhere.

I guess easiest way (though maybe not the most clever) to remove duplicated chars is to copy in this for loop passed string to another one, omitting repeated characters.

Answer (score 2):

One example, It does not modify input string and returns a new dynamically allocated string. Pretty self explanatory I think:

```
char *new_string_without_dups(const char *input_str, size_t len)
{
    int i = 1;
    int j = 0;
    char tmpstr[len+1] = {0};

    for (; i < len; i++) {
        if (input_str[i] == input_str[i-1]) {
            continue;
        }
        tmpstr[j] = input_str[i];
        j++;
     }

     return strdup(tmpstr);
}
```

Don't forget to free the returned string after usage.

Note that there are several ways to adapt/improve this. One thing now is that it requires C99 std due to array size not being known at compile time. Other things like you can get rid of the `len` argument if you guarantee a `\0` terminated string as input. I'll leave that as excercises.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea behind the code is right, but you are making two fundamental mistakes:

1. You return a `char []` from a function that has `char` as return type. `char []`, `char *` and `char` are three different types, even though in this case `char []` and `char *` would behave identically. However you would have to return `char *` from your function to be able to return a string.
2. You return automatically allocated memory. In other languages where memory is reference counted this is OK. In C this causes undefined behavior. You cannot use automatic memory from within a function outside this very function. The memory is considered empty after the function exits and will be reused, i.e. your value will be overwritten. You have to either pass a buffer in, to hold the result, or do a dynamic allocation within the function with `malloc()`. Which one you do is a matter of style. You could also reuse the input buffer, but writing the function like that is undesirable in any case where you need to preserve the input, and it will make it impossible for you to pass `const char*` into the function i.e. you would not be able to do do something like this:

`const char *str = "abbc"; 
... doubleletter(str,...);`

If I had to write the function I would probably call it something like this:

```
int doubleletter (const char *in, size_t inlen, char *out, size_t outlen){
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    if (!inlen) return 0;
    if (!outlen) return -1;
    out [j++] = in[0];
    for (i = 1; i < inlen; ++i){
        if (in[i - 1] != in[i]){
            if (j > outlen - 1) return -1;
            out[j++] = in[i];
        }
    }
    out[j] = '\0';
    return j - 1;
}

int main(void) {
    const char *str1 = "aabbaa";
    char out[25];
    int ret = doubleletter(str1, strlen(str1), out, sizeof(out)/sizeof(out[0]));
    printf("Result: %s", out);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using 2 indices to modify the string in-place:

```
void remove_doubles(char *str)
{

    // if string is 1 or 0 length do nothing.
    if(strlen(str)<=1)return; 

    int i=0;   //index (new string)
    int j=1;   //index (original string)


    // loop until end of string
    while(str[j]!=0)
    {
        // as soon as we find a different letter,
        // copy it to our new string and increase the index.
        if(str[i]!=str[j])
        {
            i++;
            str[i]=str[j];
        }

        // increase index on original/old string
        j++;
    }

    // mark new end of string
    str[i+1]='\0';

}
```